# issue accessing xml data from simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an issue accessing xml data loaded with simplexml_load_string.

First the data is retrieved with curl from this API
http://aesitelink.com/dataservice/DataServiceapi.asmx?op=GetInverterData

The expected answer has the following syntax :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="DataService.API">string</string>
```

As an example, I get the following result from my curl request

```
<rws_response><InverterData InverterId='66531' RecordsLeft='0'><Data Time='1448273400'><p i='PAC' dec='1'>22599</p><p i='IAC' dec='1'>99</p><p i='UAC' dec='1'>2279</p><p i='FAC' dec='2'>5002</p><p i='PDC' dec='1'>23545</p><p i='IDC' dec='1'>37</p><p i='UDC' dec='1'>6442</p><p i='Temp1' dec='1'>244</p><p i='Temp2' dec='1'>331</p><p i='Energy' dec='0'>2</p><p i='TotalEnergy' dec='1'>698351</p><p i='State' dec='0'>4</p></Data><Data Time='1448274000'><p i='PAC' dec='1'>29162</p><p i='IAC' dec='1'>127</p><p i='UAC' dec='1'>2296</p><p i='FAC' dec='0'>50</p><p i='PDC' dec='1'>30099</p><p i='IDC' dec='1'>47</p><p i='UDC' dec='1'>6471</p><p i='Temp1' dec='1'>248</p><p i='Temp2' dec='1'>335</p><p i='Energy' dec='1'>24</p><p i='TotalEnergy' dec='1'>698355</p><p i='State' dec='0'>4</p></Data></InverterData></rws_response>
```

Then, I use the simplexml_load_string function (with trim as suggested on several posts I read) this way :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( trim($xmlString) );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

As a result, in the $xml var, I get

```
<pre>SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] =&gt; <rws_response><inverterdata inverterid="66531" recordsleft="0"><data time="1448273400"><p i="PAC" dec="1">22599</p><p i="IAC" dec="1">99</p><p i="UAC" dec="1">2279</p><p i="FAC" dec="2">5002</p><p i="PDC" dec="1">23545</p><p i="IDC" dec="1">37</p><p i="UDC" dec="1">6442</p><p i="Temp1" dec="1">244</p><p i="Temp2" dec="1">331</p><p i="Energy" dec="0">2</p><p i="TotalEnergy" dec="1">698351</p><p i="State" dec="0">4</p></data><data time="1448274000"><p i="PAC" dec="1">29162</p><p i="IAC" dec="1">127</p><p i="UAC" dec="1">2296</p><p i="FAC" dec="0">50</p><p i="PDC" dec="1">30099</p><p i="IDC" dec="1">47</p><p i="UDC" dec="1">6471</p><p i="Temp1" dec="1">248</p><p i="Temp2" dec="1">335</p><p i="Energy" dec="1">24</p><p i="TotalEnergy" dec="1">698355</p><p i="State" dec="0">4</p></data></inverterdata></rws_response>
)
</pre>
```

My goal is to navigate through the 'rws_response' xml structure and get the info from the 'p' tagged elements.
I tried to have access to the content with $xml->{'0'}, but the result of

```
print_r($xml->{'0'});
```

is empty

```
<pre>SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
</pre>
```

How should I proceed ?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Ok, actually I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Collaborating with another brain was the way to go (thanks Martin ;o)

I should have more taken care of the '=>' sign.
Actually the string within the answer

```
<string xmlns="DataService.API">string</string>
```

is actually handled as as string ! No kidding.
Therefore, I had to re-apply the simplexml_load_string function.

I downloaded the server answer locally, for the ease of the demonstration and to avoid showing the credentials. The result.xml file has the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="DataService.API">&lt;rws_response&gt;&lt;InverterData InverterId='66531' RecordsLeft='0'&gt;&lt;Data Time='1448440200'&gt;&lt;p i='PAC' dec='0'&gt;0&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='IAC' dec='0'&gt;0&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='UAC' dec='0'&gt;230&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='FAC' dec='0'&gt;50&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='PDC' dec='0'&gt;0&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='IDC' dec='0'&gt;0&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='UDC' dec='1'&gt;6262&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='Temp1' dec='1'&gt;154&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='Temp2' dec='1'&gt;212&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='Energy' dec='0'&gt;0&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='TotalEnergy' dec='1'&gt;698929&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='State' dec='0'&gt;2&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;Data Time='1448440800'&gt;&lt;p i='PAC' dec='1'&gt;3894&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='IAC' dec='1'&gt;17&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='UAC' dec='1'&gt;2295&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='FAC' dec='2'&gt;4999&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='PDC' dec='0'&gt;429&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='IDC' dec='1'&gt;8&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='UDC' dec='1'&gt;5476&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='Temp1' dec='1'&gt;158&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='Temp2' dec='1'&gt;238&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='Energy' dec='0'&gt;0&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='TotalEnergy' dec='1'&gt;698929&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p i='State' dec='0'&gt;4&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/InverterData&gt;&lt;/rws_response&gt;</string>
```

So the following code worked for me

```
 <?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

  $urlBase  = 'http://localhost/result.xml';
  $options=array( CURLOPT_URL            => $urlBase,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
                  CURLOPT_FAILONERROR    => true );

  $CURL=curl_init();
  if (!empty($CURL)) {
    curl_setopt_array($CURL,$options);
    $xmlString = curl_exec($CURL);    

    if (curl_errno($CURL)) {
      $error = "curl_exec error : " . curl_error($CURL);
    }
    else {  
      $xml = simplexml_load_string( trim($xmlString) );
      $xml2 = simplexml_load_string( trim($xml) );

      echo '<pre>';
      $lastData = count( $xml2->InverterData->Data ) - 1;
      if ( $lastData > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $xml2->InverterData->Data[$lastData]->p as $p) {
          foreach($p->attributes() as $a => $b) {
              echo $a .' = ' . $b . '<br/>';
          }
          echo $p . '<br/>';          
        }        
      }
      echo '</pre>';     
    }
    curl_close($CURL);  
  } 
?>
```

and the result is

```
i = PAC
dec = 1
3894
i = IAC
dec = 1
17
i = UAC
dec = 1
2295
i = FAC
dec = 2
4999
i = PDC
dec = 0
429
i = IDC
dec = 1
8
i = UDC
dec = 1
5476
i = Temp1
dec = 1
158
i = Temp2
dec = 1
238
i = Energy
dec = 0
0
i = TotalEnergy
dec = 1
698929
i = State
dec = 0
4
```

Hope this could help anybody working with this API.